# Recreate the default pushViewController animation programmatically (without a navigation controller)

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview

I want to create a View outside of the visible screen and push in it (like the default pushViewController animation), but I cannot create the UIView outside. I was trying this code here, but it doesn't work. The View gets always created and displayed in the current UIScreen bounds. That means instead of both views, the one to get pushed out and the one to get pushed in, only the view that goes out "moves", the new view just sits at it's place.

In the the .m of the view to show:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // set the views frame off the screen
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(320, 0, 320, 460);
}
```

In the method that actually does the transition:

```
-(void)showOverview:(UIViewController *)sender  //sender = mapviewController
{
    NSLog(@"overview");
    // current view (frame) = mapviewCOntroller.view
    CGRect outFrame = self.view.frame;

    if (!self.overviewViewController) {
        self.overviewViewController = [[UCOverviewViewController alloc] init];
        self.overviewViewController.transitionDelegate = self;

        // create a new View for the overview
        [self.overviewViewController.view setCenter:self.view.center];
        [self.view.window addSubview:self.overviewViewController.view];
        [self.view.window bringSubviewToFront:self.mapViewController.view];
    }

    CGRect inFrame = self.overviewViewController.view.frame;
    outFrame.origin.x = outFrame.origin.x-outFrame.size.width;  
    inFrame.origin.x = self.view.frame.origin.x;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations: ^{
        [self.view setFrame:outFrame];
    }];  
}
```

**EDIT: this is my final code, at least the important part. Now, the view thats currently visible gets slider off screen at the same time the off-screen view gets slide in.**

```
-(void)showOverview
{
    if (!self.overviewViewController) {
        NSLog(@"OverviewViewController created!");
        self.overviewViewController = [[UCOverviewViewController alloc] init];
        self.overviewViewController.transitionDelegate = self;
        // add the subView
        [self.view addSubview:self.overviewViewController.view];
        [self.view sendSubviewToBack:self.overviewViewController.view];
    }
    CGRect outFrame = self.mapViewController.view.frame;
    CGRect inFrame = self.overviewViewController.view.frame;

    outFrame.origin.x -= outFrame.size.width;
    inFrame.origin.x = self.view.frame.origin.x;
    self.isOverviewViewVisible = YES;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations: ^{
        [self.mapViewController.view setFrame:outFrame];
        [self.overviewViewController.view setFrame:inFrame];
    }];
}
```

Comment: Could you post how you add the view and then push it in?  Also, instead of doing .window.frame... do .bounds

Comment: yes, see edited. the problem is, when I add the overviewView, it is immediately in place where the old view was.

Comment: So, you can get into that if block if self.overviewViewController is nil, then you create the view and assign it to self.overviewView, then you overwrite self.overviewView with a potentially nil object.  Then you reset the frame of the overviewView to an unknown(from this snippet).  You also shouldn't be adding the view to the window.  I also can't see what outFrame will be.  My guess is that, since you are seeing the view appear, then self.mapViewController.view.center is the center of the view/window it appears in.

Comment: no if i don't set the center the view is a bit off to the top, because of the status bar. that's not the problem. The problem is how do I create a view that is not on the screen!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem is this line.

```
        self.overviewView = self.overviewViewController.view;
```

You're overriding the view you created with the view you already have.

the following is not a great way to do it but it should work with what I think you have.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
      self.overviewViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(320, 0, 320, 460);
      self.overviewViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
}
```

Then you want another action to do the animations.

```
  [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations: ^{
    self.overviewViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,460);  
  }];
```

Comment: no. the current view is self.view ... self.overviewView is a property of the Rootcontroller (self). the overviewViewController handles the new view, and it gets loaded from a nib. so without this line, I don't get the view I want to be displayed at all, the view will be blue (as you can see above)

Comment: But you're creating it on the line before then just throwing it away?

Comment: I'm trying to place the view outside of the screen. this is the main point of my question. I cannot place a view from a nib outside the window, thats why I assign it (or trying to) to a view that got created outside the window

Comment: I think what I have will do what you want although not in a great way, based on what I think you have. the first line that I commented on you're getting rid of the object you just created with the alloc/init that you placed in self.overview by placing the contents of self.overviewViewController.view into it on the next line, which I believe is probably coming from your nib.

Comment: no it doesn't work. What I have is the upper view sliding to the left (correct, had that before), but the new view only gets uncovered, it doesn't move

Comment: You've changed the code significantly since you first stated the problem and I really don't understand what you're asking for at this point. It almost sounds like you just want to use a UINavigationController. Can you be more clear about what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: yes it's basically the pushViewController animation, but without a viewController ;)

Answer (score 0):

There are weird and incorrect things in your code that make it confusing to understand what is actually going on, but... forget about using the window anywhere.  The only thing you need to worry about, is this.  Say View A is your main view.  View B is the view you want outside and to come in over A.  Then, create B either from nib or manually, add it as a subview to view A, and before you enter the animation block to move it into place, make sure that the current frame is set to {ViewA.bounds.size.width, 0, ViewB.bounds.size.width, ViewB.bounds.size.height}.  Assuming you want it to come in from the top right.

Comment: Say I have ViewA and it to slide off to the side and show ViewB. If I add ViewB to ViewA, ViewB is "part of ViewAs hirachy" and gets added to the view that slides off screen. so I cannot add ViewB to the View I want to hide, but must add it to the window

Comment: If thats the case, then use 3 views.  You should only have one view  added to the window.

Comment: But the problem doesn't change. As long as I add a View to another, it's part of it. When I add ViewA as the "root" view, and then add two more to it, I have the same exact problem.